# Tomcat Web-App on Azure App Service 404-0 error

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created a Microsoft azure web app and configured java version 8 and tomcat 9 (Auto update). As per their documentation , I have uploaded my WAR file using KUDU in the web-app folder (ROOT.war my file name).

When I created the web-app without the deployment it did render the home page as Java TomCat Ready and as soon as I have deployed the ROOT.War file in my new Resource group it is now giving me 404 error.

The sub-status is 404 -"0" and I am not sure what has gone wrong the same deployment was working yesterday in the same resource group and now if I try to browse the URL of my web-app I get 404 error. I have done all sorts of research and trials but no help.
Can someone help me where I can find n fix this one?

Update (04/24) RESOLVED:- Finally something came to my help and that was the CATLENA LOGS under the Logs (using KUDU portal)-->> Application Logs. Issue was with the DATABASE Connection to my Azure Postgres SQL which had SSL REQUIRED enabled. The Application settings for the WAR File web-app needed the SSL setting in the connection string. Fixing that fixed my issue. NEEDED the SSL=TRUE ${POSTGRES_URL} =. jdbc:postgresql://abcd-corp-chatbotpgsql.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/chatbotsqldb?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory

Comment: You could check is there any situation you have in the doc.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting#the-client-is-receiving-404-messages

Comment: Thank you George, I was manage to solve the issue earlier.